# large text is not floating right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with form fields and I want to float labels to right, but when text in label is large - float is not working.

**Css**

```
 .col-xs-6 label{
      float: right;
    }
```

My Code [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7deQdBpBP4iXAp8YFVrn?p=preview)

**Where I'm wrong?**

UPD:
About

```
label{
  text-align: right;
}
```

here [is example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QKfMKbORgM1o3Q2APY0Y?p=preview) it solve just large text problem. But

```
label{
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

is working fine)

Comment: use text-align:right

Comment: it is working, but text on label is large and when it starts from right reach to left) You can give to label width and use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: _“Where I'm wrong?”_ - in assuming that floating would affect how text content is aligned; it works on _elements_, not their content. And with larger text, your label will take the full available width (or almost full, easy to check using browser dev tools, or by giving it a background color), so that floating doesn’t have much of an effect any more. And btw., you are rather violating bootstrap’s grid concept here, by not having any `row` elements, and nesting `col-` elements directly into each other … that can have unexpected/unwanted effects, so better do this properly.

Comment: is this solve your problem?
https://plnkr.co/edit/KI9O05uq1kit3NbXvdhp?p=preview

Comment: @mimi unfortunately as I see it's broken(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `text-align:right;` on `<label>` (if that is what you mean with "float is not working"):

```
label {
  text-align:right;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: oh, right. but it needs 2 property `.col-xs-6 label{
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}` couse if I add only `text-align:right;` large text will align right, but small text - not

Answer (score 1):

```
label  {
  text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

giving also float to input parent

I mean like this part which i edit for you

```
        <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
          <label style="text-align:right">Some description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
```

and other part can be like this